# Is it possible to use cancan with two ability class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm using rails 3.0.9, cancan 1.6.7 and devise 1.4.8

I'm using two devise models(User and Admin) for different log-in and registration process

So I want to divide the abilities depend upon the logged-in user(resource), because there are more than
70 models and only 10 models are common for both type of users(here more than 50 models and views are only used by Admin users)

I want to implement two Ability class(UserAbility and AdminAbility) and the devise helper method current_user/current_admin should be passed to UserAbility/AdminAbility

Example:

In ApplicationController.rb file

```
    def current_ability
        if current_user
            @current_ability = UserAbility.new(current_user)
        elsif current_admin
            @current_ability = AdminAbility.new(current_admin)
        end
    end
```

From the above my questions,

1. Is multiple ability class is possible in cancan, if possible then how to create it because I tried

   `rails g cancan:user_ability`

   but I got error as **Could not find generator cancan:user_ability**.
2. How to choose the appropriate Ability class for the logged-in User/Admin.
3. If a controller is accessed by both the User and Admin, then how can I get the currently logged-in User/Admin's object

Is there any other solution for this?

Any one please help to solve this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

...that said, you can use multiple ability models directly if you prefer:

```
class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all
  end
end

class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin)
    can :manage, :all
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # overriding CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  def current_ability
    if current_account.kind_of?(AdminUser)
      @current_ability ||= AdminAbility.new(current_account)
    else
      @current_ability ||= UserAbility.new(current_account)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes i tried for this only, but I tried lot to create another cancan Ability class but I can't (may be i don't know the right syntax)

Comment: You don't need a generator -- just make a new file in `app/models` and `include CanCan::Ability`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need multiple ability classes for that:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user_or_admin)
    user_or_admin ||= User.new

    common_rules(user_or_admin)

    if user_or_admin.kind_of? Admin
      admin_rules(user_or_admin)
    else
      user_rules(user_or_admin)
    end
  end

  def common_rules(user_or_admin)
    # can :verb, :noun
  end

  def admin_rules(admin)
    can :manage, :all
  end

  def user_rules(user)
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

CanCan will ultimately be calling `Ability.new()` with either model, but that's perfectly fine, since you can check what kind of object you received. You can, of course, delegate to other objects if you prefer; it's all just Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @willglynn, I'll go for it and please tell me, is it possible to call a helper method which returns currently logged-in User/Admin's object every time in view or there is any other way to get this object

Comment: That depends on the rest of your application. It's certainly possible, but I can't tell you how.

Comment: Classy solution. Neat

Comment: If your single `ability.rb` file gets unwieldy, take a look at separating them out into individual files, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738376/cancan-abilities-in-separate-file/25723811?stw=2#25723811

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented part of [@willgiynn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748560/5803973) solution, modifying the `current_ability` methot in the **application_controller.rb**.

On **ability.rb**:

```
class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all
  end
end

class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin)
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

On **application_controller.rb**

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= current_admin ? AdminAbility.new(current_admin) : UserAbility.new(current_user)
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will add to what [willgiynn has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748459/3480449). It seems that I had to add some more code to make it work. I found the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772257/3480449)

Add the following to the *application_controller.rb*

```
  def current_ability
    if admin_signed_in?
      @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin)
    else
      @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
  end
end
```